# Using not exist in a nested selected statement in data entities asp

Tags: c#, asp.net, join

I am new to ASP.NET and am trying to write a query that is no problem in SQL but I can't do in C#.

I have two tables:

**towns**
 t_id (Primary)
 t_desc

**TownCounty**
 tc_id (primary )
 co_id (county id )
 t_id (from the town table)
 t_active (Y/N)

What I want to do is display all the towns that are not assigned to a specific county (co_id) (i.e. "DUB") and, if they are assigned to that county, display them if they are not active (t_active = "N").

In SQL, I wrote the following statement and it worked great

```
select a.t_desc as "Town " from town a
where not exists(
select * from  towncounty b where 
b.co_id like "DUB" and 
b.t_active = "Y" and
b.t_id = a.t_id)
```

Now I am trying to get it to work in ASP.NET (C#). I have written the following statement but alas to no avail:

```
IEnumerable<Town> Towns = (from co in handyman.townCounties
where co.co_id != county_id || t_active = "N" 
join to in handyman.towns on co.t_id equals to.t_id into coto 
from subcoto in coto.DefaultIfEmpty() 
select new Town 
{ 
   Id = subcoto.t_id, <br/>
   Name = subcoto.t_desc <br/>
});
```

trying to do a left join but its returning a mess. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I sorted this out ages ago but cant remember what i did now, no longer have the code, just wanted to close the question, sorry for not being helpful